# TypeScript 2.4.1 using Array.map -> TS1109 Expression expected. TS2554 Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017, typescript2.0

I got the following error which I assumed was due to a typo from me. However I can't find out what I did wrong - I have only supplied two parameters and not three as you can see below.

```
this.props.cases.map((case, index) => { rows.push(<TableRow case={case} key={index} />) })
```

Error:

> TS1109 Expression expected. TS2554 Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this error occurs because `case` is a reserved word. Fixed it like this:

```
this.props.cases.map((useCase, index) => { 
    rows.push(<TableRow case={useCase} key={index} />) 
})
```

List of reserved words in TypeScript for future reference:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2536#issuecomment-87194347